# Using SVN with Rational Application Developer(RAD) 7.0 or with Rational Software Architect(RSA) 7.0

Tags: svn, ibm-rad, ibm-rational

We are using version 7 of IBM RAD/RSA (Rational Application Developer/IBM Rational Software Architect).

There are options to connect the same with CVS but there are no options to to connect it with SVN. Do we need to install some plugins for the same? Can you please suggest the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further googling, I found the following link on IBM website:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21255671

which points to a plugin from eclipse:

http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=technology.subversive